# Google's location-based services versus third-party services

Tags: applications, gps

Since Google offers various location-based services for which it uses its maps, known as Google Maps, what is so special about third party software programs that also provide location-based services? Don't those make use of Google Maps, which Google in turn bought from NASA? Is there any legal restriction that Google puts for those third-party programs?

I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about Google's [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) for using Google Maps APIs or Google Earth APIs. That should define the legalities of using their data.

The APIs are used by 3rd-party application developers so they can use Google Maps/Earth data in their applications. They can build on top of that, providing additional functionalities. (e.g. Foursquare used to use Google Maps, for their check-in app).

However, there's a limit to how much data a 3rd-party application can use/access for a given period of time. Beyond that limit, 3rd-party application developers have to pay. This is similar to the limit that Twitter has for 3rd-party Twitter clients (like Falcon Pro, which recently reached this limit; thus, not being able to display Twitter feed in their app).

Comment: Wow, you've given me a holistic view. Great.

Comment: @softwarelover You're welcome. :)